# Dynamically pass array column

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins

How to pass dynamically the array column to this function,
here for ex. it is `IdRemoveuser`,
I want to pass some other column name for eg. `firstname`

```
 function cleanerNewUser(arr, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       var cur = arr[i];
       if (cur.IdRemoveuser == id) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        break;
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
function cleanerNewUser(arr, id, columnName) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var cur = arr[i];

        if (cur[columnName] == id) {

            arr.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and call the function like

```
cleanerNewUser(array, id, 'IdRemoveuser');
```